# Ardour Doesn't show any plugin GUI

Tags: gui, ubuntu-studio, ardour

I have [Ubuntu Studio](https://ubuntustudio.org/tour/audio/) with its version 5 of [Ardour](https://ardour.org/)[Ardour 5.12.0
"Working Backwards" (rev 1:5.12.0-3)],  but none of the plugins shows it. I read in a forum to find a checkbox in GUI configuration, but there isn't any GUI in the configuration. Is there any limitation in Ardour 5 that comes installed on Ubuntu Studio?

I don't remember what forum I found the checkbox mentioned, but it is also mentioned in this Ardour's manual link: http://manual.ardour.org/working-with-plugins/working-with-ardour-built-plugin-editors/
(Right in the first phrases in "generic plugin editor" instructions)

Comment: Please click [edit] and tell us which version of Ubuntu Studio you have. Please don't click Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].

Comment: Which plugins? Shows what? Which forum? Which checkbox? No idea what you're talking about...

Comment: @Caio It would also be helpful to click [edit] and add the link to what you read in a forum about that missing checkbox. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].

Comment: I believe you mean [this](http://manual.ardour.org/working-with-plugins/working-with-ardour-built-plugin-editors/), please confirm. Seems there are some changes in Ardour, I can't find this too, even if I can find this option in `~/.config/ardour5/config` but changing that manually doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Mook765: Yes, that's exactly the issue. May there be a problem with the version of Ardour that comes in Ubuntu Studio? Because none of the pluguns I tested is running its GUI. I tested Guitarix pluguns (so as freeverb), but many many others that come in ubuntu, so it doesn't seem to be a specific plugun's problem, but some problem happenning in ardour, so as this checkbox we mentioned that kind of "doesn't exist" in our Ardour.

Comment: @Caio The freeverb plugin doesn't seem to have it's own GUI and opens a generic GUI, it seems to depend on the plugin. Other guitarrix plugins (but not all) open their own GUI, the same I see for Calf plugins.

Answer (score 0):

@Mook765: Wow! Thank you! I was trying lots of plugins and was sure no plugin would show their GUI. Now I tryed a Calf analyser and "Voilà" It showed!
I still see as weird the fact that "a-inline spectrogram" and "a-inline Scope" that are visualization plugins don't show a GUI instead of the generic, but I got happy to see Calf Analyser is showing beautifuly!

I may be saying rubbish, but I'm starting to think that the plugins that Ardour separates by category are the ones that don't show the GUI, cause now I see that all Calf plugins are separated as "unknown". Sorry about my "laymaness" and I hope new users can be helped by this post. Really thank you guys for the answers!!